# asp.net uploading image to server

Tags: asp.net

I am uploading image to the server in an asp.net page.Here is the code..

**Code**:

```
protected void Button2_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

           //resimyolu = "~/r/" + FileUpload1.FileName;
           FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/r/a.png"));
           FileUpload1.SaveAs("d:/upresim/a.png");
           Image1.ImageUrl = "~/r/a.png";

        }
```

the 'r' folder is the image folder in my project.when I  add a picture to the 'r' folder at runtime,it works succesfully on local IIS ,but when I publish my project and host it on a server(remote server) the web page is opening in the browser ,but when I click button2 to add client image(which client user selected from his computer) to the project an error appears like below..

```
Runtime Error 
Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine. 

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a <customErrors> tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This <customErrors> tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".
```

Comment: Your error doesn't say much. Set your customErrors mode to remoteOnly. You can then run this page from the server and see the correct error.

Comment: here is the correct exception : System.Web.HttpException: The SaveAs method is configured to require a rooted path

Comment: I bought your time,thank you

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the error message, disable the custom errors on your web.config to see what's the issue.

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I do: here is excaption :     Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: The SaveAs method is configured to require a rooted path, and the path '~/r/a.png' is not rooted.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line.

```
FileUpload1.SaveAs("d:/upresim/a.png");
```

Change it to will help.

```
FileUpload1.SaveAs("d:\\upresim\\a.png");
```

Avoid using such hardcoded paths if your code. You will face issues when you change machines. `Server.MapPath` is always a better way to go. If you do not want to save in your web dir, you should always take the base path from configuration.

Comment: but tihis line is running succesfull.the problem is at FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/r/a.png")); because it can't fount 'r' folder on server